# Storing single data values in the database

Tags: arrays, json, database, model

I wanted to know what the best way is to store single data values in a database. Values you only need one field of.

I have a couple of ideas.

1. Storing all fields in a single_data_table with a id, key and value column.
2. Storing it as a json object in the database.
3. Storing it as an array in the database.

Which one is the best way? Or might there even be better ways?

Or is it just easier to keep single data values as static data on the webpage?

Comment: If it's a row in your database, you should represent it as a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At my current job we use a separate `settings` table for that, with two columns: `key` and `value`. And then there's a simple function to retrieve or save a setting:

```
function setting($key, $value = null){
    $setting = DB::table('settings')->where('key', $key)->first();
    if(is_null($value)){
        return $setting->value ?? null;
    }

    if(isset($setting)){
        $setting->value = $value;
    }else{
        $setting = $setting ?: new stdClass();
        $setting->key = $key;
        $setting->value = $value;
    }

    DB::table('settings')->insertOrReplace((array) $setting);
    return true;
}
```

It is used like so:

```
$phone = setting('phone'); // Get the phone setting
$url = setting('url', 'http://example.com'); // Set url setting
```

Comment: So all loose settings from all the pages are stored in one table which also can be edited on a restricted page for example?

Comment: Do you btw have a form that allowes the user to edit the data or does it need to be hard coded like your example?

Comment: Yes, everything that doesn't belong to a proper model just goes to the settings table. Like "last_site_update_time", for example: it is only one value for everybody. We don't have UI for that, but you could create your own quite easily. Hope this helps :)

Comment: It’ll help definitely, I was looking for an api, and found out about nova flexible content but people kept telling me it was not handy or so

Comment: I also had another quick question, for example if i want to have a slideshow and a couple of posts on my homepage, i would just have to load in two models into the home controller i guess right? One for the slides and one for the posts